# SonarQube - Set tags via REST API - Powershell - Invoke-RestMethod

Tags: powershell, sonarqube, invoke-restmethod

I'm attempting to set tags via the SonarQube REST API, however, the REST API doesn't come with a lot of examples for different scenarios.

In my case I'm attempting to set the tags for a given projectKey with an API Key. I want to use Invoke-RestMethod instead of Curl, since I'll be running the script in powershell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution - tested on SonarQube 9.2.4
The biggest hassle is to figure out how the authentication works.
This script is inteded to be used in f.ex. a build agent. The API for SonarQube is weird and not necessarily easy to use.

```
$sonarQubeUrl = "https://YOURSONARQUBEINSTANCE"
$apiUrl = "/api/project_tags/set"
$projectKey = "YourProjectKey"
$tagsUrl="&tags="
$tags="your,own,tags"
$sonarKey = "YOURAPIKEY" + ":"

function SetTagsForProjectKey(){
    $EncodedText =[System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($sonarKey))

    $Headers = @{
      "Authorization" = "Basic $EncodedText"
      "Accept" = "application/json"
    }
    $Body= @{
       grant_type = "client_credentials"
       project = $projectKey
       tags = $tags
    }
    $url = $sonarQubeUrl + $apiUrl
    write-host "Url is set to $url"
    try {
        Invoke-RestMethod –Method POST –Uri $url –Headers $Headers –ContentType "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" –Body $Body
    }
    catch {
        write-host "Error when uploading new data for $name : $_ "
    }
}
```